# Pandas - List of Dataframe Names?

Tags: python, list, pandas

I've done a lot of searching and can't find anything related. Is there a built-in function to automatically generate a list of Pandas dataframes that I've created?

For example, I've created three dataframes: `df1` `df2` `df3`

Now I want a list like: `df_list = [df1, df2, df3]` so I can iterate through it.

Comment: Why not `df_list = [df1, df2, df3]` without the string markers?

Comment: You're right--that's what I meant--I updated the question

Comment: Pandas doesnt keep track of your created DataFrames for you. Maybe there is some hacky way to get them, but normally you should just create a list and add the DataFrames to it whenever you create one that you want to "keep".

Comment: That's what I figured since I couldn't find anything out there on this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My hacky way to get them (-:

Python provides a built-in [**`globals`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) that returns a dictionary where keys are named variables and values are the objects themselves.  We can use a list comprehension and iterate over all values of the dictionary and only get those that are of type `pd.DataFrame`

```
d = globals()
df_list = [v for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, pd.DataFrame)]
```

Comment: Follow-up question: the list that was returned had the df names in quotes. Is there a way to return a list without quotes around the names? Current output: `['df1','df2','df3']` Preferred: `[df1,df2,df3]`

Comment: If you used my code, you should not have names at all.  You should have the actual objects as the list elements.

Comment: You're right. After re-reading my question, I wasn't clear enough. My goal is to return a list of dataframe names, which I can then use to iterate through.

Comment: If you do that, you'll have something like `['df1']`.  Which is what you wanted.  Then you'll have to use `eval(df_list[0])` to access it.  It would be a ton better to keep it as a dictionary `df_dict = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, pd.DataFrame)}`.  Then you can have names and dataframe objects.

Comment: @WaltReed in fact, you can make the list and dictionary and have the best of both worlds.  `df_dict[df_list[0]]`

Answer (score 1):

%who_ls DataFrame

This is all dataframes loaded in memory as a list

all_df_in_mem = %who_ls DataFrame